# Multiple Calls inside loop

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I'm new with Angular so I need some help, My problem is to call http get I use service there is my first get

My first Service

```js
getFirstData() { return this.http.get<FirstDataResults ('http://myurl.com/api/Classes/ads', httpOptions);
```

My component TS file

```js
this.data.getFirstData().subscribe(
    data => {
        this.firsobjects = data.results;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => this.getComplementData(this.firstobjects)
);
```

Until now always is fine can fetch my data and when it's completed i run the second function called getComplementData

My Second Service

```js
getSecondData(idFirstObject: String) {
    return this.http.get<ComplementDataResults>(
  'http://myurl.com/api/Classes/Complement?' +
  'where={'"idFirstObject":"' + idFirstObject + '"}',
   httpOptions);
}
```

My component TS file

```js
getComplementData(firsobjects) {
this.number = 0;
for (var _i = 0; _i < firsobjects.length; _i++) {
    this.data.getSecondData(firsobjects[_i].id).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            var a = (data.results);
            this.firsobjects[this.number].complements = a;
        }, err => console.log('error ' + err),
            () => console.log('Ok ')
        );
    }
}
```

I Have problem with this second function i can fetch all data but the problem is that the complement data are not ordered
from what I understood of the http call inside my loop are parallel so async.

My question is, how I can  run my http get inside the loop sync to get ordered results.

Thank you !

Comment: you cloud use indexing or mapping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use rxjs' [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```js
getComplementData(firsobjects) {
    this.number = 0;
    let calls = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < firsobjects.length; _i++) {
        calls.push(this.data.getSecondData(firsobjects[_i].id));
    }

    forkJoin(...calls).subscribe(
        data => { // Note: data is an array now
            var a = (data[0].results);
            this.firsobjects[this.number].complements = a;
        }, err => console.log('error ' + err),
        () => console.log('Ok ')
    );
}
```

Something like that. Enjoy.

Comment: I added a loop inside subscrib and it's work thank you :) 

      forkJoin(...calls).subscribe(
        data => { // Note: data is an array now
          for (var _j = 0; _j < data.length; _j++) {
          this.firsobjects[this.number].complements =data[_j].results;
            } 
        }, err => console.log('error ' + err),
        () => console.log('Ok ')
      );